# C# Razor Website Download custom extension file 404 error

Tags: c#, download, http-status-code-404, file-extension

I have a simple anchor link that needs to download a file from the server. The file name is:  "**RT350Z_cfg.modbus**".  I believe the server cannot recognize the file type so it is giving me a **404 error**.

The exact path of the file is: 
`~/uploads/UNITS/docs/VFD/RT350Z_cfg.modbus`

My **cshtml** file simply has this:

```
 <a target="_blank" href="@(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/uploads/UNITS/docs/VFD/RT350Z_cfg.modbus"))">Download File</a>
```

When I click on the link I get a 404 error not found. I have triple checked that the file exists in that location of the server.

I then modified the extension to a `*.txt` file and revised the hyperlink to look for the txt file.

```
<a target="_blank" href="@(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/uploads/UNITS/docs/VFD/RT350Z_cfg.txt"))">Download File</a>
```

When I physically modified the extension to a `*.txt` file, and then changed the hyperlink - the file downloaded just fine.

How do I allow my web application to download custom file extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some versions of IIS do not serve 'unknown' files.
You can configure your web.config to treat the file as you want:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".modbus" mimeType="text/plain" />
```

or for binary:

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".modbus" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
```

You can read more about it at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap#configuration).

Comment: Awesome! This works perfectly! I actually found an alternative work-around but this is much simpler. I'll accept this as the answer once the time-limit lets me

Answer (score 1):

Usually, I create an *Action* in my controller that returns a `FileContentResult` and simply create an `ActinLink` in the view to point to it. This is more *MVC* way of downloading a file. Plus you have full control of it.

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile()
{
    //Use your own way to read the file. Or even you can pass a file stream to it.
    var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/DataFile.anyExt"));

    return File(file, "contentType", "yourDesiredFileName.anyExtOfYourChoice");
}
```

And in the view, use the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click me to Download", "DownloadFile")
```